# read large xml file in vb6

Tags: xml, vb6, xml-parsing

I am trying to load XML file which is 0f 250MB. But it is not able to load File.
please guide me.

i m showing the code i Am using for that.

```
frmArvindKMM.CD.Filter = "Text File(*.xml)|*.xml|All File |*.*"
frmArvindKMM.CD.ShowOpen

If frmArvindKMM.CD.FileName = "" Then
MsgBox "Import Failed", vbCritical + vbOKOnly, "AMN & Co."
Exit Sub
End If


Set xmlDoc = New DOMDocument30
If frmArvindKMM.CD.FileName = "" Then
    MsgBox "Failed to import"
Exit Sub

ElseIf xmlDoc.Load(frmArvindKMM.CD.FileName) Then
       xmlDoc.async = False
Else
    MsgBox "Failed to import"
    Exit Sub
End If
```

Comment: see also the question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6036481/using-sax-parsing-to-edit-and-write-xml-in-vb6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use **SAX parser** which will allow you to **dynamically** load your XML file.

Refer The Following Link 
http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-us;266228

Comment: SAX is a parser, and doesn't really "load" anything in the sense of parsing and constructing a towering DOM object out of the XML.  Of course using SAX you can create your own more compact DOM either ad hoc based on Collections of Collections, etc. or using an MSXML DOM object - by filtering out things you don't care about.  Or you can process the XML data "sequentially" as it is parsed, e.g. copy "row" node data to a database table.